# How to use EF connection string and ADO.Net connection string in same project

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, connection-string, membership-provider

In normal EF connection string which I use is like this:

```
<add name="NorthwindEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=******;initial catalog=******;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

But when I try to add Ado.Net Membership system in the current project, the connection string have to be like this:

```
<add name="MembershipEntities" 
     connectionString="data source=*****;initial catalog=*****;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

How to handle this situation?

I'm putting this question with solution for anyone else's benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem, when add the connection string name here (connectionStringName):

```
<membership>
          <providers>
              <clear/>
              <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
                  type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                  connectionStringName="NorthwindEntities"
                  enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                  enablePasswordReset="true"
                  requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
                  applicationName="/"
                  requiresUniqueEmail="true"
                  passwordFormat="Hashed"
                  maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                  minRequiredPasswordLength="3"
                  minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
                  passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                  passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
          </providers>
      </membership>
```

it brings this error: "Keyword Not Supported: Metadata"
to solve this error we need add another connection string in   node. and change connectionstring name  `connectionStringName="MembershipEntities"`

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NorthwindEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*****;initial catalog=*****;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="MembershipEntities" connectionString="data source=*****;initial catalog=*****;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```